# Find a package by name in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, search

I know the name of Java *package* and I want to find it in project.

- How to do it fast in IntelliJ IDEA?
- Is there any keyboard shortcut?

Comment: For v.13+ this should be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22771685/191246

Answer (score 24):

Open `Project View` tool window, switch to the **Packages** view mode, click on the gear icon, enable **Flattern Packages** option, disable **Show Modules** option.

Start typing the package name to activate the **speed search**.

---

Another option is to use `Navigate` | **Class**, type `your.package.*`, select some class, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for the **navigation bar** popup, use arrows to select the package, press <kbd>F4</kbd> (may not work if navigation bar is not floating, but enabled in the View menu instead).

Comment: I do not recommend the first approach on huge projects. Even after a long loading phase the GUI freezes again when searching.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more easy way, though specifically, it wont only search packages.

What you can do is a global search:

> Ctrl + Shift + F

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of focusing on the Project tab and then knock the keyboard, just look what is happening, maybe help you:)

Comment: Sometimes project tab contains lots of packages, it's hard to find the packege you need. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another easier way is to use the "Search Everywhere" option 
1. Double click Shift button.
2. Enter the package name.

Though the result will not be on the top of the list, its easy to locate.