# IntelliJ IDEA: how to search for a folder / directory / package name?

Tags: intellij-idea

I wish to search just *directory* (folder) names and *packages* within the modules of my current project.

How can I do this?

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> allows me to find a
  class
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> allows
  me to find a symbol

Is there a function for that allows me to search just directories, folders and package names?

---

I'd like the result of this search to be that the directory / package sought is highlighted in the "Project" box.

For example, if I type in "model.feed" then then I get this:

[image: Intellij Proejct Packages Box View]

and preferably while I'm typing that a list of any directories matching would be shown in real time (in the same way as classes are when you do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4 (Ultimate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a package by name in Intellij IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098104/find-a-package-by-name-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 97):

In IntelliJ IDEA 13, you can use Goto File (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and enter the directory/package name with a slash afterwards. Then you'll see all the matching directories in your project.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for updating this, I'm still on IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4, but in the event that I upgrade, I'll try this out, cheers

Comment: Awesome! As expected, idea even accepts the asterisk before the slash, i.e. this works `partialdirname*/`. @SimonB This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Not answering the question. In his question, he already mentioned that he has tried the command Ctrl+Shift+N. What this does is open the file, but highlight the location in the project explore!

Comment: Command-Shift-O on my Mac keybindings, but works well for me.

Comment: Wow that is why i love JetBrains

Comment: In newer versions you also have there a filter, in an upper-right corner, and can search only for directories

Answer (score 5):

I propose this as a partial solution to your query.

The following steps will allow you to find a file or directory or package name or jar name that is *visible in the project view*.

Caveats stated explicitly below, but give this a go.

1. Click on the root folder in the Project View.
2. Start typing words that you want to search on to find packages/files/folders/jars in the project view
3. A tool tip will appear that contains the text `Search For:` along with the text that you have
   entered.
4. The Project View will then highlight the first folder or file that matches the text that you have entered.

This may be close to what you are looking for.

The only caveat is that this search is constrained to those entities currently visible in the Project View so if you want to search a particular part of the project it appears that you have to expand those folder within the Project View. (From my testing of this in IntelliJ Ultimate Version 11.)

One way to work around this is to go to the root element in your project. Perform a partial traversal of where you want to go then by pressing enter you open the folder that you have landed on and then that search is completed.

Starting typing text again after pressing Enter will recommence the search from the current item in the Project View.

So by experimenting with this feature you can interactively walk around your project in the Project View in a dialog-box-free manner.

As a side note you can use the letters Camel Case style to traverse and find classes in the ProjectView

Comment: Hello Rob, thank you for your reply, the "currently visible" caveat is a bit restraining, otherwise your suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

### Windows/Linux

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

### macOS

<kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>  + <kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

On mac it is

```
CMD + Shift + O
```

at least for intellij 14.1

Answer (score 1):

If you try

`CTRL + SHIFT + F`

You can do a global file search (like eclipse CTRL + H).

In the file search, you can select which folder to search for, what file type to search for, case sensitive etc, all the normal stuff.

Global Replace is

`CTRL + SHIFT + R`

`(Mac replace CTRL for CMD)`

[image: find in path]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, perhaps my question wasn't clear enough (I'll edit it in a minute). 
I'd like the result of this search to be that the directory / package sought is highlighted in the "Project" box and preferrably that a list of any directories matching would be shown in real time (in the same way as classes are when you do "CTRL Shift N")

Answer (score 1):

If you have the file open in the editor and can't figure out the location in the project view

**WINDOWS:**
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

From Select In... pick the first item, Project View

Answer (score 0):

It seems IntelliJ doesn't directly support this.  Here are the best alternatives I've thought of so far:

I suggest these steps if there is nothing in the folder yet (Windows):

- Windows:

  - Right click on the project root, and choose "show in explorer"
  - In the search box on the top right, search for the folder you want (e.g. *META-INF*)
  - Right click, "open folder location"
- Linux/Unix/Cygwin:

  - Copy the path instead, (in the right-click menu),
  - cd to the directory using a console or cygwin,
  - use the 'find' utility.  E.g. type `find . -iname 'SomeFolderName*'`

If there is already something in the folder, I suggest you do this:

- Ctrl-Shift-F to search for files
- Enter the directory name inside a wildcard pattern (eg. `*/META-INF/*`)
- open the first file that occurs in that folder
- Click on the circular target icon to "scroll from source" (at the top of the project panel).

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself wanting to search for folders/packages often, you can use the `Go to File` command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) and set a **filter** on `Directories` so that you can quickly search for directories and packages. The filter will be **saved for the next time** you use `Go to File`. As a demonstration:

- Use `Go to File` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) and click on the `filter` icon (funnel-shaped) on the top right of the search box. Disable/unselect all other selections and only keep `Directories` selected.
- Try searching -- you should only see directories and packages in the result.
- Try using `Go to File` again -- you should find that the filter **still exists**

**Caveat**: While using 'Search Everywhere'(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>), you will be forced to use the filter you set earlier on `Go to File`.